# I want to edit my program so rather than having user enter seat number in a text box to make reservation they can select it in the listbox

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How would I go about changing to code to eliminate the textbox that takes the value of the seatnumber and makes the reservation they can simply select which seat they want from the seating chart in the listbox and click make reservation. I know there's some unused code in here that needs cleaned up just ignore it i've been playing around with different ways to do this.

Heres the form code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reservations
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        Flight curFlight;
        List<Flight> flightlist = new List<Flight>();

        Flight flight1 = new Flight("Cessna Citation X", "10:00AM", "Denver", 6, 2);
        Flight flight2 = new Flight("Piper Mirage", "10:00PM", "Kansas City", 3, 2);

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MakeReservations();
            DisplayFlights();
            SetupFlights();


        }

        private void lstFlights_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            curFlight = (Flight)lstFlights.SelectedItem;
            txtDepart.Text = curFlight.DepartureTime;
            txtDestination.Text = curFlight.Destination;
            string[] seatChart = curFlight.SeatChart;
            DisplaySeatChart(seatChart);
        }

        private void DisplaySeatChart(string[] seating)
        {
            lstSeatChart.Items.Clear();
            for (int seat = 0; seat <= seating.GetUpperBound(0); seat++)
            {
                lstSeatChart.Items.Add("Seat: " + (seat + 1) + "       " + seating[seat]);
            }
        }

        private void SetupFlights()
        {


            //flightlist.Add(flight1);
            //flightlist.Add(flight2);


        }

        private void MakeReservations()
        {
            flight1.MakeReservation("Dill", 12);
            flight1.MakeReservation("Deenda", 3);
            flight1.MakeReservation("Schmanda", 11);
            flight2.MakeReservation("Dill", 4);
            flight2.MakeReservation("Deenda", 2);
        }

        private void DisplayFlights()
        {
            lstFlights.Items.Clear();
            lstFlights.Items.Add(flight1);
            lstFlights.Items.Add(flight2);
        }

        private void btnMakeReservation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            int seatNum;
            string[] seatChart = curFlight.SeatChart;

            if (txtCustomerName.Text != "" && txtSeatNum.Text != "")
            {
                name = txtCustomerName.Text;
                seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeatNum.Text);
                curFlight.MakeReservation(name, seatNum);

                lstSeatChart.Items.Clear();

                DisplaySeatChart(seatChart);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill out Name and Seat Number.", "Reservation Error");
            }
        }

        private void btnEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string name;
            int seatNum;
            string[] seatChart = curFlight.SeatChart;

            if (txtCustomerName.Text != "" && txtSeatNum.Text != "")
            {
                name = txtCustomerName.Text;
                seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeatNum.Text);
                curFlight.EditReservation(name, seatNum);

                lstSeatChart.Items.Clear();

                DisplaySeatChart(seatChart);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Fill out Name and Seat Number.", "Reservation Error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

HERES THE CLASS CODE

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Reservations
{
    class Flight
    {
        private string mPlane;
        private string mDepartureTime;
        private string mDestination;
        private int mRows;
        private int mSeats;
        private string[] mSeatChart;

        public Flight()
        {
        }

        public Flight(string planeType, string departureTime, string destination, int numRows, int numSeatsPerRow)
        {
            this.Plane = planeType;
            this.DepartureTime = departureTime;
            this.Destination = destination;
            this.Rows = numRows;
            this.Seats = numSeatsPerRow;

            // create the seat chart array
            mSeatChart = new string[Rows * Seats];

            for (int seat = 0; seat <= mSeatChart.GetUpperBound(0); seat++)
            {
                mSeatChart[seat] = "Open";
            }
        }

        public string Plane
        {
            get { return mPlane; }
            set { mPlane = value; }
        }

        public string DepartureTime
        {
            get { return mDepartureTime; }
            set { mDepartureTime = value; }
        }

        public string Destination
        {
            get { return mDestination; }
            set { mDestination = value; }
        }

        public int Rows
        {
            get { return mRows; }
            set { mRows = value; }
        }

        public int Seats
        {
            get { return mSeats; }
            set { mSeats = value; }
        }

        public string[] SeatChart
        {
            get { return mSeatChart; }
            set { mSeatChart = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.Plane;
        }


        public void MakeReservation(string name, int seat)
        {
            if (IsFull(seat) == false)
            {
                if (seat <= (Rows * Seats) && mSeatChart[seat - 1] == "Open")
                {
                    mSeatChart[seat - 1] = name;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Seat is taken.", "Reservation Error");

                }

            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Plane is full please choose another flight.", "Reservation Error");
            }
        }

        public void EditReservation(string name, int seat)
        {
            if (seat <= (Rows * Seats) && mSeatChart[seat - 1] != "Open")
            {
                mSeatChart[seat - 1] = name;
            }
            if (seat > mSeatChart.GetUpperBound(0))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid seat number.", "Reservation Error");
            }
            else
            {
                if (mSeatChart[seat - 1] == "Open")
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No such reservation exists.", "Reservation Error");
                }
            }

        }

        public bool IsFull(int seat)
        {
            if (seat >= (Rows * Seats) && mSeatChart[seat - 1] != "Open")
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is simple rather than

```
seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeatNum.Text);
```

use

```
seatNum = lst.SeatChart.SelectedIndex + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

An item in your seat chart collection should first have an identifier. Once you have that, that identifier (or a description, name, etc.) All 'Open' seats should be added to a list box that the user can select. Upon reservation, you simply determine which list box items are selected. You can do this with or without data binding.

```
    List<Seat> seats;

    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seats = new List<Seat>
        {
            new Seat { Identifier = "A1", Description = "A1 - Window" },
            new Seat { Identifier = "A2", Description = "A2 - Center" },
            new Seat { Identifier = "A3", Description = "A3 - Aisle" } 
        };

        listBox1.DataSource = seats;
        listBox1.DisplayMember = "Description";
        listBox1.ValueMember = "Identifier"; 
    }

    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // get selected seat
        foreach (Seat selectedSeat in listBox1.SelectedItems)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(selectedSeat.Identifier);
        }
    }
```

Of course you can play around the example and display only those seats that are free. You can do that several ways, one of them is by adding a flag on your Seat class.

Comment: i'm trying to understand exactly what you mean is there a way I can change                         
seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(txtSeatNum.Text);
to something like seatNum = Convert.ToInt16(lstSeatChart.SelectedItem);
I don't really understand how to make an identifier or exactly what you mean by that.